# Evaluation of hypergeometric type continued fraction

Tags: hypergeometric-functions, continued-fractions

Is there a (possibly hypergeometric-type) explicit evaluation of the
continued fraction
$$a-\dfrac{1.(c+d)}{2a-\dfrac{2.(2c+d)}{3a-\dfrac{3.(3c+d)}{4a-\ddots}}}$$
Even the special case $d=0$, $a=1$ would be interesting. Note that
$$\tanh^{-1}(z)=\dfrac{z}{1-\dfrac{1^2z^2}{3-\dfrac{2^2z^2}{5-\ddots}}}$$
but that does not seem to help.

Comment: I didn't check all the details, but seems like it is possible using Norlund's continued fraction https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.7.E5

Comment: I did check all these CF before posting, nothing seems to work. Note that there is only a superficial resemblance between $1,2,3...$ and $1,3,5,,,$: in this latter case, the CF is classical as I mentioned.

Comment: Did you try imposing constraints in 15.7.5-6 such as $c-1=(a+b-1)z$? This will give exactly the CF of the form you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, a more general substitution does work and gives me a (complicated) hypergeometric answer in the case $d=0$, which is the main case I am interested in. I can post it if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Nemo: in fact, I believe there is a misprint in NIST 15.7.E5: there should be a factor of $c$ in front of the quotient of $F$.

Comment: I don't think so. see https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.1.E2

Comment: @Nemo, you are right, very confusing notation, I thought that $F$ was ${}_2F_1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is found in [1] $\S 82$, Satz 5.  It covers the case where the numerator $a_n$ is polynomial of degree $2$ in $n$  and the denominator $b_n$ is degree $1$.

If I plugged in correctly, we get for your continued fraction:  Let
$a, c, d$ be complex numbers satisfying: $c \ne 0, a \ne 0, a^2 \ne 4c$, and
$(a^2-4c)/a^2$ is not a negative real.  Then the value is
$$
{\frac { \left( d+c \right) \sqrt {{a}^{2}-4\,c}+a \left( c-d
 \right) }{2c} 
\;{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,{\frac {d+c}{c}};{\frac { \left( 3\,c+d \right) \sqrt {{a}^{2}-4\,c}+a \left( c-d \right) }{2c\sqrt {{a}^{2}-4\,c}}};{\frac {\sqrt {{a}^{2}-4\,c}-a}{2\sqrt {{a}^{2}-4\,c}}}\right)}^{-1}}
$$

The sign of the square-root is chosen so that $\displaystyle\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-4c}}$ has positive real part.

(The numerator ${{}_2F_1}$ has a zero in there, so it turns out to be constant.)

[1] Oskar Perron, *Die lehre von den Kettenbrüchen*, 2 Auflage 1929

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nemo's suggestion, the answer for $d=0$ is
$$\dfrac{a-\delta}{2c}\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{n!}{((3+a/\delta)/2)_n}\left(\dfrac{1-a/\delta}{2}\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{a-\dfrac{1^2c}{2a-\dfrac{2^2c}{3a-\ddots}}}\;,$$
with $\delta=\sqrt{a^2-4c}$.